# return value 'no row' if max query return a NULL

Tags: mysql, null, max

I have a table. From that I need to return Max value of a field. If that row is empty or if it doest satisfy some conditions the query will return `NULL`. I need to return NO ROWS if the max returns a `NULL`. How can i do it? I have tried [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html), [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html),[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) But I am not able to get what i need.

Sorry, it was my mistake. I dont mean to say the word 'NO ROWS', More clearly i dont want to get any rows(no rows should be returned) if it returns `NULL`. I apologies again for my mistake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use HAVING, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(field)
FROM yourtable
-- GROUP BY somefileds
HAVING MAX(field) is not null
```

HAVING specifies a condition for values of the aggregated columns.

Answer (score 4):

Try this ::

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(field), 'NO ROWS') FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

Use IF function in your select

`SELECT IF(MAX(field) IS NULL, 'NO ROWS', MAX(field)) FROM table`